# Syntax error in Mysql Trigger 1

Tags: mysql, triggers

Where syntax error in my code? I can't find...
Code:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `devices_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `devices`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.status <> OLD.status THEN
        INSERT INTO `test`.`devices_history` (`ip`, `status`, `date`) VALUES (OLD.ip_address, NEW.status, NOW());
    END IF;
END
```

He says that error:

> SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 */

Comment: missing the delimiter at the beginning.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty How i must write it's delimiter... i writed, but he didn't help..

Comment: For example, add `DELIMITER $$` at the beginning, then put a `$$` after your last `END`, then add a `DELIMITER ;` to restore the standard situation.

Comment: @Cynical thank you... add `DELIMITER //`  at the beginning, after creat the trigger...